# SublimeText - How to override HTML auto comments?

Tags: html, syntax, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext

While working on a custom  tmLanguage that extends HTML in SublimeText, i tried to create a special marking for auto-commenting ('Ctrl'+ '/').

while the default auto comments in HTML is written in  form, i want it to be 
--[ ]--.

i saw several places where it is said that the right way of doing so is adding it to the language file is:

```html
           <key>shellVariables</key>
           <array>
               <dict>
                  <key>name</key>
                  <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                  <key>value</key>
                  <string>--\[</string>
               </dict>
               <dict>
                   <key>name</key>
                   <string>TM_COMMENT_END</string>
                   <key>value</key>
                   <string>\]--</string>
               </dict>
```

Which doesn't seems to work..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Just edited my post in case that wasn't obvious. I want to know how to make it work...

Comment: Have you tried to create a `.tmPreferences` file as a sibling of your `.tmLanguage` file? Take as an example the `Comments.tmPreferences` that I mentioned in my answer. Let me now so I can update it if this works..

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try it when I'll get to work...

Comment: @JoaquínO it worked!
I opened a Comments.tmPreferences and specified "settings" value that contained "shellVariables" dictionary. in there i included the "TM_COMMENT_START" and "TM_COMMENT_END" of the language. more info on other tmPreferences  files can be found here:
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SyntaxHighlightTools

Comment: It's good to hear. Just updated my answer with the solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this in Ubuntu 15.04 and it worked:

First check that this directory exists `/opt/sublime_text/Packages`. You should have lots of `*.sublime-package` files.

One of those files is `HTML.sublime-package` which is the one we need to tweak.

You'll probably need to use `sudo` to modify this file.

I found this bash function that we will use in the next step (I changed from `vi` to `nano` for user-friendly reasons).

```
zipedit(){
    echo "Usage: zipedit archive.zip file.txt"
    unzip "$1" "$2" -d /tmp 
    nano /tmp/$2 && zip -j --update "$1"  "/tmp/$2" 
}
```

[Source](https://superuser.com/questions/647674/is-there-a-way-to-edit-files-inside-of-a-zip-file-without-explicitly-extracting)

Now, navigate to the folder

```
cd /opt/sublime_text/Packages
```

Paste the `zipedit` function in your terminal.

Then execute it passing this parameters

```
zipedit HTML.sublime-package Comments.tmPreferences
```

Now `nano` text editor opens in your terminal, and you have to modify the `<string />` attr for your HTML comments from `&lt;--` to `--[` and so on..

Then you just need to restart Sublime Text and the magic is done.

---

**WARNING:** this may come with unknown/unwanted results such as bad syntax highlighting in well-formed html files.

---

### Update

To make this at a package level, create a `Comments.tmPreferences` file in your package directory and put content like this inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
   <key>name</key>
   <string>Comments</string>
   (....)
   <key>settings</key>
   <dict>
      <key>shellVariables</key>
      <array>
         <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <string>--[ </string>
         </dict>
         <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>TM_COMMENT_END</string>
            <key>value</key>
            <string> ]--</string>
         </dict>
      </array>
   </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I need a solution in the package level, preferably on the tmLanguage file since this package is used throughout my company and I need it bundled with all the rest of the sublime-package...

Comment: And also, i'm using windows.